# How add something in "<head>" with Drupal 7.x?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, head

i have big doubt... is correct how i add something (for example link for publisher google plus, or meta tag or external resource css):

```
function mysubtheme_page_alter($page) {

$viewport = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
     '#tag' => 'meta',
     '#attributes' => array(
         'name' =>  'viewport',
         'content' =>  'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
 );
 drupal_add_html_head($viewport, 'viewport');


 $googleplus = array(
     '#type' => 'html_tag',
     '#tag' => 'link',
     '#attributes' => array(
        'href' =>  'https://plus.google.com/+google-plus',
        'rel' =>  'publisher')
 );
 drupal_add_html_head($googleplus, 'googleplus');


 $pinterest = array(
     '#type' => 'html_tag',
     '#tag' => 'meta',
     '#attributes' => array(
        'name' =>  'p:domain_verify',
        'content' =>  '7680eb52326ae9ee9e415d0ad')
 );
 drupal_add_html_head($pinterest, 'pinterest'); 


 $fontawesome = array(
     '#type' => 'html_tag',
     '#tag' => 'link',
     '#attributes' => array(
        'href' =>  '/sites/font-awesome.min.css',
        'rel' =>  'stylesheet')
 );
 drupal_add_html_head($fontawesome, 'fontawesome');
}
```

I hope you can help me :) sorry for my english

**edit** I ASK THIS also because those are my latest changes and now i noticed that if i logged and see my website with `Firefox` there aren't CSS ! ABSURD!

Now i have 3 ways:

1. not correct how add something in `head`
2. **Issue Firefox (44.0.2)**
3. issue module ADVANCED CSS/JS AGGREGATION

**EDIT 2.0**  It was a problem with firefox (i reset it and issue was solved)... however i would like to know if this way to add in `head` is right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal_add_html_head adds output to the HEAD tag of the HTML page. This function can be called as long as the headers aren't sent.

More info at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7

Comment: But is right my code, with drupal_add_html_head in function mysubtheme_page_alter($page) ?

Comment: This function can be called as long as the headers aren't sent. Try and move your code inside your custom module (maybe hook_init ). Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to drop the following in my template.php

```
    function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
      if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
        $meta_description = array(
                '#type' => 'html_tag',
                '#tag' => 'meta',
                '#attributes' => array(
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'content' =>  'blah blah blah'
                )
        );
        $meta_keywords = array(
                '#type' => 'html_tag',
                '#tag' => 'meta',
                '#attributes' => array(
                    'name' => 'keywords',
                    'content' =>  'some, keywords'
                )
        );
        drupal_add_html_head( $meta_description, 'meta_description' );
        //drupal_add_html_head( $meta_keywords, 'meta_keywords' );

        drupal_add_html_head_link(array(
          'rel' => 'publisher',
          'href' => 'https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxx',
        ));
      }
    }
```

Publisher is needed only on the front page hence the  drupal_is_front_page

Comment: and if is added also to other pages of website ? is an issue ?